# .js active only for resolution >767px

Tags: javascript, css

I have tricky header and when I scroll down... header-bar, menu and logo are smaller. But I don't want that on the mobile device. How to activate that .js only for resolution >767px?

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 350 )
        $(".top-nav li").css("padding", "20px 15px 0px"),
        $(".logo img").css("margin", "7px 0 0 0"),
        $(".logo img").css("height", "50px");
    else
        $(".top-nav li").css("padding", "30px 15px 10px"),
        $(".logo img").css("margin", "13px 0 0 0"),
        $(".logo img").css("height", "57px");
});
```

Comment: `var screenRes = $(window).availWidth();`
`if(screenRes > 767){`
`//code here`
`}`

Comment: `if (screen.width > 767) { do event handler`

Comment: @jplara sth is wrong here. I still can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you search for is Responsive Webdesign and should not be implemented all-alone in JS.

Implement it in css instead like this (just for example):

```
@media(min-device-width: 767px){
  .top-nav li {
    padding: 20px 15px 0px;
  }
}
```

Regards

Comment: On similar line you can have your nav set to display:none on a media query like this,  @media all and (max-width: 767px) { .top-nav { display: none; } }